# How do I code an app that allows HC-06 to connect with my app using Android studio

Tags: android

I’m trying to make an app that allows connection to a HC-06 module, and is able to use Bluetooth activity to send notifications even when you’re in another app. Similar to the Bluetooth terminal app, but it has an extra background bluetooth activity. I tried searching for tutorials and guides but they only taught how to pair bluetooth devices and did not explain how to make an app. Can anyone help? Even a starting point would do.

Answer (score 0):

A series of youtube tutorials [here](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8KHMzpp6JITZ2JxTgWqDH2) will make you get started with bluetooth classic programming in android. This is a really nice tutorial series for Bluetooth classic version which uses Bluetooth sockets and threads for reading and writing from/to the sockets. Hence it is compatible with HC06 module.

*A friendly note:* **`Bluetooth classic != Bluetooth Low Energy`**.

Here is its content:

- [Enabling Bluetooth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8R2C86BIUc&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8KHMzpp6JITZ2JxTgWqDH2&index=1&pp=iAQB)
- [Bluetooth discoverability](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVD_8PrvG4Q&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8KHMzpp6JITZ2JxTgWqDH2&index=2&pp=iAQB)
- [Discover devices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hv_-tX1VwXE&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8KHMzpp6JITZ2JxTgWqDH2&index=3&pp=iAQB)
- [How to pair](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJ0JQXcNNTA&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8KHMzpp6JITZ2JxTgWqDH2&index=4&pp=iAQB)
- [Sending/Receiving data part 1/4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fz_GT7VGGaQ&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8KHMzpp6JITZ2JxTgWqDH2&index=5&pp=iAQB)
- [Sending/Receiving data part 2/4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGtMNk9lriw&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8KHMzpp6JITZ2JxTgWqDH2&index=6&pp=iAQB)
- [Sending/Receiving data part 3/4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1_JA4vMHy0&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8KHMzpp6JITZ2JxTgWqDH2&index=7&pp=iAQB)
- [Sending/Receiving data part 4/4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sifzY2SA1XU&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8KHMzpp6JITZ2JxTgWqDH2&index=8&pp=iAQB)
- [Sending data from a thread to an activity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwBhDnvKGd8&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8KHMzpp6JITZ2JxTgWqDH2&index=9&pp=iAQB)

Comment: Thanks so much, I will finish the tutorial then come back if I have any questions.